# Enabled WOL - Now my computer powers on by itself

Tags: linux, debian, wake-on-lan

To use the wake on LAN feature of my onboard network interface, I had to enable "Wake on PCI-Express" in my BIOS settings. WOL works fine now.
The only problem is that my computer turns itself on without me sending a MagicPacket. Sometimes it happens only a few seconds after I shut it down using "poweroff" or "shutdown -h now". Sometimes it "waits" for one or two minutes.
I have disconnected all unnecessary components. Only power,  display cable and ethernet are left.
I use Proxmox (Debian) and have set it up to enable WOL via

```
ethtool -s eth0 wol g
```

"g" is to be used if you only want a MagicPacket to be able to wake up the machine.
Is there anything I have to do before I shutdown the computer to prevent it from waking up by itself?

Thanks for your help,

Kevin

***UPDATE***

After I shut down the machine it seems to power itself on only one time. When I turn it off after that, it stays off. Also the source for the wakeup seems to be "inside" the computer. When I unplug the ethernet cable immediately after shutdown, it powers on nevertheless.

***UPDATE #2***

Last night I gave up and installed an old PCI NIC. I disabled "Wake on PCI-E" and enabled "Wake on PCI". Everything works fine now using WOL to wake up the machine via the second NIC.

Before that I already tried several other PCI-E NICs (Intel, Broadcom, D-Link).

Answer (score 0):

You have to look and check the POST (Power-on self-test) settings usually located in POWER section in your motherboard BIOS, there's something like "restore last state" or anything similar to this which describes what to do when power supply unit gets the power whether to ON the PC or keep the PC turned off.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already considered that. "Power on after power failure" is set to "Off".

Comment: Try changing NIC (LAN) card if you have it spare and also see other BIOS settings relating to network. You can also change your power socket and give it a try.